# Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Name at line 7

Tags: rest-api

[image]I have write classes using rest API.I have paste same code in another org it is working fine. can you please suggest what correction should I do and how?

```
  @RestResource(urlMapping='/restapiIntegration/*')
global with sharing class MyRestResource {

  @HttpPost
    global static String doPost(String name, String phone, String website) {
        Account account = new Account();
        account.Name = name;
        account.phone = phone;
        account.website = website;
        insert account;
        return account.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Correction for what ? What is the issue here ?

Comment: I think my org is not support this but am not sure my org having namespaces. If I paste same code another org it's working fine. can you suggest me why this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce Apex is not case sensitive. Giving a class `Account` a variable name `account` can confuse the parser.

Try renaming `account` to something like `acct` or `theAccount`

By the way, I ran this code and was not able to get it to break, so this could be a long shot.